# Canvas element is invisible in Chrome after lockscreen

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, canvas, createjs

Working on Canvas mobile game using CreateJS library. Everything goes smoothly except this issue:

When I exit browser by Home Button or Lock the phone, after lock screen or relaunch of browser, Canvas element is invisible. Refresh solves the problem.

I tried chrome element inspector and as you can see on the screenshot, element exists and it's on right position. I don't know why it's invisible.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Probably your canvas as been resized, or the innerHTML of one of its parents have been edited.

Comment: I have one function, which resize canvas on window size change - to optimize canvas position. But this only affects canvas width/height and top/left properties. As you can see on the screen, canvas element position is correct. It's leaving me feeling like it has transparency property set to 0. But it's not. Do you have any other variants why it happens?

Comment: if you do resize the canvas with its `width`and `height` properties as you should, then the canvas and all its context's properties will be cleared , you will then have to redraw everything. If you do resize with css, that's bad, but it's a bug the canvas get cleared.

Comment: I do resize with `width` and `height` properties and my stage is updating on every `requestAnimationFrame` tick. Maybe ticker dies on lock-screen and then not comes alive without refresh ?

Comment: Have you tried adding a focus event listener on the DOM which instructs the canvas to redraw (stage.update)? Might be worth a try.

Comment: Yes requestanimationframe stops when the window loses focus, you have to call it again on focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grab the pixels, you'll find that it's actually still there.  This is possibly a bug in Chrome 49/50 (which I'm trying to find an acceptable workaround for).

If you change the canvas width to 0 and then back to the correct size, or rotate your device a few times *or* press the running tabs button and swap back again you could find it'll start being visible again.

It seems to be some hibernate problem with the hardware acceleration :/

Comment: Looks like you gave me the best explanation :)

Comment: No problem - If I find a solution that works, I'll post here.  Currently I listen for a tab-switch event, grab all canvases in the DOM, grab the size + resize to 0 and back.  On some tests we're also grabbing the pixels, resizing and then painting contents back
This means every paint cycle the context must be re-acquired and any transforms re-applied.

This is not ideal for me, as I'm currently wanting to patch around 100 games with one 'fix'.  Bad times :)